# Drawing JButton dynamically

Tags: java, swing

Okay so, I'm trying to make a tic tac toe game that has a background image and a few buttons. After extending JFrame:

```
Dimension screen;
GUI()
{
    setUndecorated(true);

    screen=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setSize(screen.width, screen.height);
    setLocation(0, 0);
    System.out.println(screen.width+" : "+ screen.height);
    try {
        setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("path"))) ) );
    } catch (IOException e1) {          
    }

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);   
}
```

As for the JFrame, it now should work fine on every pc I run it on, since it gets the screenSize and uses it to set the JFrame size. But:

```
    JButton buttons=new JButton[9];
    int x=110, y=260;
    for(int i=0;i<buttons.length;i++)
    {
        buttons[i]=new JButton("");
        buttons[i].setSize(350,150);
        buttons[i].setLocation(x,y);
        y+=(i%3==2)?160:0;
        x=(i%3==2)?110:x+400;                           
        add(buttons[i]);            
    }
```

Those buttons work fine, or get drawn fine inside the image, only in my PC, since I set the location and size according to MY screenSize. So I need some help on how to draw these buttons to work on every PC aswell. Is there some algorithm that I can do with the getScreenSize? I can't think of any.

I've also read that I can use layout managers, but I believe the buttons won't get drawn as of how I want them., because I want the buttons to be drawn inside the image. Here's the [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMgXL.jpg), so you can imagine what I really want to do.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use layout containers you have several options here.

1) Make your JFrame non resizable and set fixed width and height
`setResizable(false);
setSize(width, height);`

2) Make you JFrame resizable and override Its resize event

Create your background images for different resolutions and screen sizes. When JFrame's size changes update background image accordingly. **For example:**

```
frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {

 public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
    if(getWidth() <=800 && getHeight() <=600) {
         setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("image1")))));
    } else if (getWidth() <=1024 && getHeight() <=768) {
        setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("image2")))));
    } else if (//more Resolutions...) {
      //ect...
    }
 }
});
```